# How to run a angular web app with express?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm having a problem with a Angularjs (v1) project with express server, when It start show me this error and where It show "ng-view" is blank, but the controller work fine,also I did run the code on apache server and It works, but when I use with express server it not works, this is the console error:

```
Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.8/$compile/tpload?p0=views%2Fhome.html&p1=404&p2=Not%20Found
Stack trace:
K/<@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:7:76
g/<@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:162:186
h/<@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:137:167
$digest@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:148:130
$apply@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:151:353
l@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:103:165
t@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:108:228
yg/</A.onload@http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:109:139
```

I did try to update angular version or reinstall It (bower), but It don't work for me.

I believe the error is produced in app.js segment of code:

```
// create the module and name it woonked
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','ngSanitize',"checklist-model"]);
    // configure our routes
    app.config(["$routeProvider","$locationProvider",function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {       
        var signed = localStorage.getItem("signed_in");
        var temp;
        var ctrl;       
        if(signed)
        {
            temp = 'views/dashboard.html';
            ctrl = 'dashboardCtrl';
        }
        else
        {
            temp = 'views/home.html';
            ctrl = 'mainController';
        }

        //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);        
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
        $routeProvider

            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : temp,
                controller  : ctrl
            })


            .when('/dashboard', {
                templateUrl : 'views/dashboard.html',
                controller  : 'dashboardCtrl'
            })  

            /*
            .when('/branches', {
                templateUrl : 'views/branches/branches.html',
                controller  : 'branchesCtrl'
            })

            .when('/branch/:deviceId', {
                templateUrl : 'views/branches/branch/branch.html',
                controller  : 'branchCtrl'
            })
            */

            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    }]);
```

**SOLVED**

Finally I found that the error was produced because I don't set route in express for use `views` path, I added `app.use('/views',  express.static(__dirname + '/kospr-mgr/views'));` and It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer without seeing your code, but as documentation says, this error occurs while trying to load a template. So you could check it in the place you pass that template url or provide some code to look at.

Comment: Hi Varo, I believe that error could be in this part of code (app.js) , I will go to update the question for put up the app.js code

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when `$compile` attempts to fetch a template from some URL, and the request fails.

To resolve this error, ensure that the URL of the template is spelled correctly and resolves to correct absolute URL. The [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network#network_panel_overview) might also be helpful in determining why the request failed.

If you are using `$templateCache` to pre-load templates, ensure that the cache was populated with the template.

For more information, see [AngularJS Error Reference - Error: $compile:tpload](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tpload).

Comment: Hi George, I did view the Angular doc reference, but It don't help me, I'm trying to resolve this issue, for now, I found that  `templateUrl` generate error in last version of Angular Route, the reference correct should be `template`, It not work for me yet, but is an advance

Comment: Hi friend, I'm sorry, the `template` work for me, but writing html code in same file, not in other file, `templateUrl` not work, and there is the error